# Does php object for each file is good idea?

Tags: php

I'm writting an php app which manages files (browsing, moving, deleting, etc.) and I need to create several functions for this.

I have two ways to code these functions.

- option 1, using objects:

  ```
  $myFile = new ofile('myFile.txt');
  $myFile->move('someDirectory');
  $myFile->delete();
  ```
- option 2, using normal functions:

  ```
  move('myFile.txt','someDirectory/myFile.txt');
  unlink('someDirectory/myFile.txt');
  ```

So my questions are:

Which solution is better?  Is it a big difference in performance?

Comment: No, the difference is in style - not in performance.

Comment: option 1 is sexier...

Comment: This question is totally legit - voting to reopen.

Comment: While using procedural functions consumes fewer memory than using OOP, the difference is really despicable and won't affect your app at all. So, I recommend you using OOP, is clenear and more escalable.

Comment: if you're a lazy bum like me, you should go with option 2

Answer (score 3):

Difference in performance is non-existant.

First option is by far better for maintainability and extensibility.

However, consider moving methods like `move`, `delete` to separate manager class, so that in the future when you have a need for a new filesystem support (S3 for example) you won't face refactoring hell.

Better yet, consider not reinventing the wheel and looking into open-source solutions, such as https://github.com/KnpLabs/Gaufrette

Answer (score 1):

I personally like the OOP approach more, because you produce a more portable, extendable, maintainable and readable code.

If you choose to go with option 1 then I highly recommend to look into [SplFileObject](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splfileobject.php). You can extend your own class from it and have many important methods out of the box.

```
$file = new SplFileObject('example.php');
var_dump($file->getRealPath());
var_dump($file->getFilename());
```

Also read about [FilesystemIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.filesystemiterator.php) and [DirectoryIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php) to not reinvent the wheel.

Comment: +1 for reusing the Spl.

Comment: I'm always wondering that so few people know about SPL's iterators and other cool extensions.